# DropInResult returning null in responce

Tags: android

I want to get nonce from server. i wrote backend in PHP that will giving token. after receiving token PaymentMethodNonce returning null.

I want to get nonce from server.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                DropInResult result = data.getParcelableExtra(DropInResult.EXTRA_DROP_IN_RESULT);
                PaymentMethodNonce nonce = result.getPaymentMethodNonce();
                String stringNonce = nonce.getNonce();
                Log.d("mylog", "Result: " + stringNonce);
                // Send payment price with the nonce
                // use the result to update your UI and send the payment method nonce to your server
                    paramHash = new HashMap<>();
                    paramHash.put("couponPrice", couponPrice);
                    paramHash.put("nonce", stringNonce);
                sendPaymentDetails();

            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // the user canceled
                Log.d("mylog", "user canceled");
            } else {
                // handle errors here, an exception may be available in
                Exception error = (Exception) data.getSerializableExtra(DropInActivity.EXTRA_ERROR);
                Log.d("mylog", "Error : " + error.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

DropInResultobject is result. That is returning null but that should be some valid information

Comment: Confirm you started the intent with **startActivityForResult**  and not **startActivity** and also check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Comment: its already startActivityForResult  not startActivity

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

```
val result = intent.getParcelableExtra<DropInResult>(DropInResult.EXTRA_DROP_IN_RESULT)

return null
```